# Setting JLabel text in Netbeans not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have used the GUI builder to make some JLabel in a JFrame. These variables are locked and I find it difficult to use them to in another class.

```
 // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
public javax.swing.JLabel title;
// End of variables declaration
```

I had to set the variables public before I could use them in a different class.

Comment: Open the file in any other editor and make those field public because most of the GUI builders don't allow user to modify the declaration through the same GUI builder.

Comment: My advice: Put the IDE aside and learn how to make a GUI with Java code.

Comment: Those framework let you update these generate file in general, of course not that they will override everything if you do an update. Now, I found strange that `title` is public, so you might be able to change that setting for the other label

Comment: yes I made title public so as to use it in a different class. Thanks for pointing things out.

Comment: [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the init method and do

```
title = new JLabel("This is my Title label. No?");
```

Comment: Note that if you can access `title` then you can simply do `title.setText("foo bar");` It will only work with that Label though

Answer (score 2):

after `initComponent()` invoked method in your constructor add for example

```
jLabel2.setText(test text);
```

Comment: @camickr I do just that my reputation is less than 15 and that is why it's not visible yet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set value to the private variables from anotber class.
If you want to do so you can pass the variable as the a parameter and set value.
Or you have to make JLable public.
`